# SQL Server product price side by side

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT     
    tbStok.sModel AS Kod, tbStok.sAciklama AS Adı, 
    SF.lFiyat AS SF, PSF.lFiyat AS PSF, 
    TL.lFiyat AS TL , USD.lFiyat AS USD
FROM         
    tbStok 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbStokFiyati AS TL ON tbStok.nStokID =  TL.nStokID 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbStokFiyati AS SF ON tbStok.nStokID =  SF.nStokID
LEFT JOIN 
    tbStokFiyati AS PSF ON tbStok.nStokID = PSF.nStokID 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbStokFiyati AS USD ON tbStok.nStokID = USD.nStokID
GROUP BY 
    tbStok.sModel, tbStok.sAciklama, SF.lFiyat, PSF.lFiyat, TL.lFiyat,USD.lFiyat
```

Above is the SQL statement I'm using.

When query started, result is 7255470 rows but I have 18867 rows in `tBstok` table.

We have product information in `tbStok` table with 2 different columns such as product code and product name. And in the other table, called `tbStokFiyati`, there are 4 different columns which I need to get.

And result is very slow!

Comment: That's an awful lot of joins. What does the execution plan look like? Is `nStokID` indexed on the `tbStokFiyati` table?

Comment: How many rows are in the `tbStokFiyati` table? Unless you have at most one row in `tbStokFiyati` for each row in `tbStok`, your query is incorrect, because it is effectively doing some CROSS JOINs between the  tbStokFiyati table.

Comment: I believe your join conditions should be referring to different columns in the `tbStok` table.

Comment: I believe, there must be an additional condition for each joined table, because you're joining table four times on only one condition, of course, you will get much more rows when there exists.

Comment: missing an join condition at a guess. Suggests nstokid is not unique in at least one of the tables

Answer (score 0):

The table needs to be more than worth separating from tbStokFiyati.

```
SELECT     
    tbStok.sModel AS Kod, tbStok.sAciklama AS Adı, 
    SF.lFiyat AS SF, PSF.lFiyat AS PSF, 
    TL.lFiyat AS TL , USD.lFiyat AS USD  
FROM   tbStok 

LEFT JOIN 
    tbStokFiyati AS TL ON tbStok.nStokID =  TL.nStokID 
                      and TL.sFiyatTipi='TL'

LEFT JOIN tbStokFiyati AS SF ON tbStok.nStokID =  SF.nStokID
                      and SF.sFiyatTipi='SF'

LEFT JOIN tbStokFiyati AS PSF ON tbStok.nStokID = PSF.nStokID 
                      and PSF.sFiyatTipi='PSF'

LEFT JOIN tbStokFiyati AS USD ON tbStok.nStokID = USD.nStokID
                      and USD.sFiyatTipi='USD'

GROUP BY 
    tbStok.sModel, tbStok.sAciklama, SF.lFiyat, PSF.lFiyat, TL.lFiyat,USD.lFiyat
```

Answer (score -1):

The first things you should be revisit when running on this kind of performance issues is the database design. Have the PKs been defined accordingly? Have you created NON CLUSTERED INDEXes over each FK to seepd up the joins? Have you created indexes over interesting columns which are being used on your queries? There is a feature you can use on SQL Server Management Studio called ***Actual Execution Plan*** to examinate what's going wrong about the query's performance.

Please take a look to [SQL Server Index Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/) for further reference.
 
There also some util links for Basic and Advanced Execution Plan understanding:
* http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/
* http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1856/sql-server-query-execution-plans-in-sql-server-management-studio/

The difference between Actual and Esitmated execution plan:
* http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/28/sql-server-actual-execution-plan-vs-estimated-execution-plan/

Comment: hi, I want to do, such as pivot table


        SELECT tbStok.sModel, tbStokFiyati.lFiyat as Price,tbStokFiyati.sFiyatTipi as PriceType
            FROM  tbStok INNER JOIN
                              tbStokFiyati ON tbStok.nStokID = tbStokFiyati.nStokID
               where sModel = '010301200015'
    
    
    this is orjinal sql, i want same make pivot look 


  [sample secreen shoot]: http://www.hanifeoglu.com/price.png

Comment: I thought you was complaining because of the performance issue (results very slow). Please edit your post and ask a clear question so we can support you properly. Regards.

Comment: yes my proplem wrong tsql proplem  because wrong  it causes sql

Comment: this final code true code
SELECT     
    tbStok.sModel AS Kod, tbStok.sAciklama AS Adı, 
    SF.lFiyat AS SF, PSF.lFiyat AS PSF, 
    TL.lFiyat AS TL , USD.lFiyat AS USD
FROM  tbStok 
LEFT JOIN  tbStokFiyati AS TL ON tbStok.nStokID =  TL.nStokID And sfiyattipi=TL
LEFT JOIN  tbStokFiyati AS SF ON tbStok.nStokID =  SF.nStokID And sfiyattipi=SF
LEFT JOIN  tbStokFiyati AS PSF ON tbStok.nStokID = PSF.nStokID And sfiyattipi=PSF
LEFT JOIN tbStokFiyati AS USD ON tbStok.nStokID = USD.nStokID And sfiyattipi=USD

GROUP BY 
    tbStok.sModel, tbStok.sAciklama, SF.lFiyat, PSF.lFiyat, TL.lFiyat,USD.lFiyat